# Making different UIElements 'active' in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have multiple UIScrollViews used as image 'filters' which are loaded in a switch statement. The switch statement is based on a UISgemgentedControllers segment index.

When i load the scrolView its works fine but on loading the next and returning the first one, I cannot scroll it but only the one I had previously set.

E.g :

Initialise 1 > Select filter 1

Initialise 2 > Select filter 2

Return to 1 > Still on filter 2 (however the scrollView is reinitialised)

Does anyone know how I can easily switch between them and for them to retain their position and allow me to access them individually?

Below is my code for one of the scrollViews (they are all the same)

Thanks in advance!

~~~ Code Below ~~~

```
- (void)layerSelected:(id)sender
{
int index = filterControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

switch (index)
{
    case 0: if (scroll == nil)
            {   
                scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
                scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
                scroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                NSInteger viewCount = 15;
                for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) 
                {
                    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
                    UIImageView *filterViewOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                    [filterViewOverlay setImage:[filterManager objectAtIndex:i]];
                    [scroll addSubview:filterViewOverlay];
                    [filterViewOverlay release];
                }
                scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * viewCount, self.view.frame.size.height);
                [self.scroll setContentOffset:currentPos1];
                [self.view addSubview:scroll];
                [scroll release];
            }
            else
            {
                [self.scroll setContentOffset:currentPos1];
                scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
            }

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the code in the segmented controller? It sounds likely that it isn't presenting it's UIImage correctly when the first segment is selected again. also Apple changed the behaviour of the buttons after 3.0. It would be worth reading here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

to see if the button behaviour you are selecting is expected.